# How to print out the form field values in the same page after the user enters submit?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to display the information below the form after you hit submit. Please help me figure this out. The submit button does not display anything. Can somebody please explain?
**Here is my HTML code:**

```
    <form id="myform" role="form">
        <label for="Name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name"> 
        <div class="dropdown"> 
        <label for="countries">Country:</label> 
        <select class="form-control" id="countries">
          <option value="">Select a Country:</option>
        </select>
        <label for="states">State:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="states">  
          <option value="">Select a State</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" onclick="showInput();">
    </form> 
    </div> 
        <label> Your input:</label>
        <p><span id='display'>
    </span></p>
```

**Here is my JavaScript code:**

```
function showInput() {
    var output_info =  document.getElementById("myform").value;

    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = output_info;
}
```

Comment: share your markup also...

Comment: FORM doesn't have a value. Each INPUT does. You have to get each value and append it to your output.

Comment: Also won't that submit button cause the page to immediately submit and refresh?

Comment: Change it to `type="button"` so it doesn't submit the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try include `name` attribute at `input`, `select` elements within `form`; use `.querySelectorAll()` with selector `"input:not([type=submit]), select"` chained to `form` to select `form` elements; `for` loop to iterate elements returned by `.querySelectorAll()`

```html
<script>
  function showInput(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var output_info = document.getElementById("myform");
    var display = document.getElementById("display");
    var data = output_info.querySelectorAll("input:not([type=submit]), select");
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      display.innerHTML += "name:" + data[i].name + " value:" + data[i].value + "<br>"
    }
  }
</script>
<form id="myform" role="form">
  <label for="Name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Name" id="Name" />
  <div class="dropdown">
    <label for="countries">Country:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="countries" name="countries">
      <option value="">Select a Country:</option>
      <option value="abc" selected>abc</option>
    </select>
    <label for="states">State:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="states" name="states">
      <option value="">Select a State</option>
      <option value="123" selected>123</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" onclick="showInput(event);" />
  </div>
</form>
<label>Your input:</label>
<p><span id='display'>
    </span>
</p>
```

Comment: This works perfectly except, every time I hit submit, it prints the info. How do I disable the submit button after clicking submit once?

Comment: @user2817815 Add `output_info.querySelector("input[type=submit]").setAttribute("disabled", true)` after `for` loop

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 <?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{

echo $_POST["Name"];
echo $_POST["countries"];
echo $_POST["states"];
}
?>
 <form id="myform" role="form" action="" method="post">
        <label for="Name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Name">  
        <label for="countries">Country:</label> 
        <select class="form-control" name="countries">
          <option value="">Select a Country:</option>
        </select>
        <label for="states">State:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="states">  
          <option value="">Select a State</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit"  name="submit">
    </form>
```